# I want to delete duplicate rows from my database table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I went through a few answers on this topic but none of them are executing on my workbench.
I have duplicate rows in my table and I want to delete all retaining only one of them. First I grouped them by Count function and then tried deleting them but it isn't working.
I tried running CTE query from old questions on the website:

```
 WITH ReferenceDP AS (
  SELECT[ReferenceId1], 
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ReferenceId1 ORDER BY ReferenceId1) AS [rn]
  FROM TABLE
)
DELETE ReferenceDP WHERE [rn] > 1
```

But it did not work.
I have attached the image of my table.
Can someone help me out with the query.
Thank You.
[DuplicateRowCount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYRn.png)

Comment: Are you really using MySQL and not SQL Server?

Comment: It's sometimes quicker to CREATE a new table , retaining only those rows you wish to keep, then delete the old table, then rename and re-index the new table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this. It basically deletes duplicate rows and keeps the highest ReferenceId

```
 DELETE t1 FROM ast_fx_all_mst t1
 INNER JOIN ast_fx_all_mst  t2 
 WHERE 
    t1.ReferenceId < t2.ReferenceId AND 
    t1.TownAreaLocality = t2.TownAreaLocality AND
    t1.ContactName = t2.ContactName
```

Comment: @SupportOfficer2 Hopefully it goes without saying, but always make a back up of your data before attempting stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delete join query and reference your table twice.

```
DELETE t1 FROM ast_fx_all_mst t1
INNER JOIN ast_fx_all_mst t2 
WHERE 
    t1.ReferenceId < t2.ReferenceId AND t1.ContactName = t2.ContactName;
```

This link might help: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

Comment: Duplicate answer