# SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js, unique

I am using sequelize and node.js. I have one column that want change it's type to unique, when I want run the migration I have this err , How can I solve it?

```
ERROR: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
```

this is my code :

```
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.changeColumn('PersonalInfo', 'ssn', {type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true
      }),
      queryInterface.changeColumn('PersonalInfoDraft', 'ssn', {type: Sequelize.STRING, unique:true
      })
    ])
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure these columns don’t have duplicate data first. If not, it will fail to change them to unique as it can’t satisfy the rule

Here is an example post on how to delete duplicate rows and keep one instance of each row. Make sure to backup your data before running deletes just in case.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63735751/14167216

Comment: yes we have duplicate data , Is there any solution for solve this?

Comment: Create a query to delete the duplicate rows and keep the one copy of each. Backup your data before the delete in case issues occur

Comment: Updated response to give example on how to delete duplicate data for your convenience